# Canvas is not showing my image using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make flappy bird using javascript, but I am having a hard time getting an image on my canvas. I can show circles and rectangles but not images.

I tried using a path to a folder with an image, but that didn't work because it couldn't find the image. I am now using a url as a source to the image and it can find the image, but it is not showing it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var bird = new Image();

bird.src = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/151-1515288_flappy-bird-png-jpg-download-flappy-bird-bird.png";

//trying to draw the img
function drawBird(){
    bird.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(bird, 250, 350);
    }
}
//trying to display pipes
function drawPipes(){
            for (var i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
                var topPipe = pipes[i].top;
                var bottomPipe = pipes[i].bottom;


                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(topPipe.xpos, topPipe.ypos, topPipe.width, topPipe.height);
                context.rect(bottomPipe.xpos, bottomPipe.ypos, bottomPipe.width, bottomPipe.height);
                context.fillStyle = "green";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 2;
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
```

I call my functions in the following update function:

```
function update(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawBird();
    drawPipes();

    if (pipes.length === 0 || pipes[pipes.length - 1].top.xpos <= canvas.width / 2 - pipes[pipes.length - 1].top.width) {
                var topPipeObj = new topPipe();
                var topPipeHeight = topPipeObj.height;
                var bottomPipeHeight = canvas.height - 200 - topPipeHeight - 200;
                pipes.push({
                    top: topPipeObj,
                    bottom: new bottomPipe(bottomPipeHeight),
                });
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
                pipes[i].top.xpos += dx;
                pipes[i].bottom.xpos += dx;
            }

            if (xp <= canvas.width / 2) {
                drawPipes();
                xp = 1300;
            }

            xp += dx;
            y += dy;
            dy += gravity;

            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }

        document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                jump();
        });

    update();
```

I could realy use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Use the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor. Make sure you pay attention to the browser console (I would not be surprised if there was a cross origin error).

Comment: I think you're never calling `drawBird`, and so `bird.onload` is never defined. Try to move `bird.onload` to the line _before_ `bird.src = ...` to make sure it runs.

Comment: Sorry @DanielDiekmeier that is my bad. The drawBird() was indeed never called, because I had an alternative class called drawCircle. I tested both of them, but neither worked. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Yogi It isn't working on my side :(.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things going wrong:

- something else is overwriting your bird
- you could be drawing outside the canvas visible area

Lets test a simplified version of your drawBird code in isolation:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var bird = new Image();

bird.src = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/151-1515288_flappy-bird-png-jpg-download-flappy-bird-bird.png";

function drawBird(){
    bird.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(bird, 1, 1, 100, 100);
    }
}

drawBird()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

You can see it draws just fine, you have to do the same with your code, simplify it until you get something working then make small incremental changes and test each to make sure nothing is broken